# .NET Core Windows Forms не срабатывает событие Scroll на форме

Tags: windows, .net, winforms, .net-core

Создаю пустое `Windows Forms` приложение по шаблону `Windows Forms App (.NET)` (не старое `Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)`). Добавляю на форму событие `Scroll`, но оно не отрабатывает. Почему?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось вот так. Событие не срабатывает скорее всего потому что свойство `CanFocus` формы равняется `false`.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    const int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;
    const int MK_CONTROL = 0x0008;

    if (m.HWnd == Handle && m.Msg == WM_MOUSEWHEEL)
    {
        int wParam = (int)m.WParam.ToInt64();
        bool control = (wParam & 0xFFFF) == MK_CONTROL;
        int delta = wParam >> 16;
        if ((delta & 0x8000) != 0)
            delta |= unchecked((int)0xFFFF0000);
        delta /= 120;

        // используем delta как-то, control - зажат ли Ctrl
    }
    else
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```